# Убрать подписи кнопок блока поделиться

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Я поставил блок кнопок справа вертикально. Как бы убрать их подписи? Чтоб только значки были как при горизонтальном расположении?

[image: Вот убрать надписи как на скрине]

Comment: https://tech.yandex.ru/share/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в свои стили `.ya-share2__title{width:0;height0;overflow:hidden;}`
Взято отсюда https://yandex.ru/blog/share/kak-iz-vertikalnogo-raspolozheniya-knopok-ubrat-podpisi-sotssetey#comment-add